# VB.NET IQueryable

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I'm using VB.NET FX 4.0 and EF.
In my code I use:

```
Dim query As System.Linq.IQueryable(Of MY_TABLE)
Dim sCondition As String = "it.DATE_IN = '" + searchDate + "'"
query = From c In MyContext.MY_TABLE .Where(sCondition ) Select c
```

There result always empty and my question is..
How to get only date portion from DATE_IN field, since the searchDate is only in format dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: Does it really not offer any way for you to perform filtering in a strongly typed manner, and avoid converting everything into strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime` to remove the time part. Also you should use a `DateTime` rather than a string value when you compare the dates.

```
Dim dateValue = DateTime.Parse(searchDate).Date
Dim query = MyContext.MY_TABLE.Where(Function(x) _
            EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DATE_IN) = dateValue)
```